# How do I get the total number of unique pairs of a set in the database?

Tags: database, math

4 items:

```
A
B
C
D
```

6 unique pairs possible:

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

What if I have 100 starting items? How many unique pairs are there? Is there a formula I can throw this into?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming, but rather about math in general.

Comment: `(n(n-1))/2` where `n` is the number of elements i.e. in your case 4 so `(n(n-1))/2` = 6

Answer (score 138):

TLDR; The formula is `n(n-1)/2` where `n` is the number of items in the set.

### Explanation:

To find the number of unique pairs in a set, where the pairs are subject to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) `(AB = BA)`, you can calculate the [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) of `1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)` where `n` is the number of items in the set.

The reasoning is as follows, say you have 4 items:

```
A
B
C
D
```

The number of items that can be paired with `A` is 3, or `n-1`:

```
AB
AC
AD
```

It follows that the number of items that can be paired with `B` is `n-2` (because `B` has already been paired with `A`):

```
BC
BD
```

and so on...

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-(n-1))
```

which is the same as

```
1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)
```

or

```
n(n-1)/2
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as (n-1)!

Comment: This is not the same as (n-1)! Which escalates much quicker.  This is similar to a Triangle number though, whose formula is (n+1)n/2 (the series is positionally off by one).  (n-1)n/2 for n=1,2,3,... =
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, ...

Comment: ```(n (n+1) / 2) - n
= ((n^2 + n) /2) - n
= (n^2 + n - 2n) / 2
= (n^2 - n) / 2
= n(n - 1) / 2```

Answer (score 95):

What you're looking for is *n choose k*.  Basically:

[image]

For every pair of 100 items, you'd have 4,950 *combinations* - provided order doesn't matter (AB and BA are considered a single combination) and you don't want to repeat (AA is not a valid pair).

Comment: Help me I'm dumb - can you throw 100 items into that equation to teach me

Comment: `n` would be the number of items (100 in your case), and `k` would be the number of elements in each set (2 in your case).

Comment: No problem.  I think most modern programming languages have *combination* functions built in.  You can also use the function `=COMBIN(100,2)` if you have Excel handy.

Comment: [Here's an online one](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html)

Comment: library(gtools); combinations(3 * 3, 2) # pairs from 9 in R (e.g. 3 x 3 factorial ANOVA)

Comment: Btw,  for `k=2` the formula simplifies to `n(n-1)/2`.

Answer (score 46):

This is how you can approach these problems in general on your own:

The first of the pair can be picked in N (=100) ways. You don't want to pick this item again, so the second of the pair can be picked in N-1 (=99) ways. In total you can pick 2 items out of N in N(N-1) (= 100*99=9900) different ways.

But hold on, this way you count also different orderings: AB and BA are both counted. Since every pair is counted twice you have to divide N(N-1) by two (the number of ways that you can order a list of two items). The number of subsets of two that you can make with a set of N is then N(N-1)/2 (= 9900/2 = 4950).

Answer (score 14):

I was solving this [algorithm](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams%20and%20found%20this%20explanation%20about%20series) and get stuck with the pairs part.

This explanation help me a lot 
https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

So to calculate the sum of series of numbers:

```
n(n+1)/2
```

But you need to calculate this

```
1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)
```

So in order to get this you can use

```
n(n+1)/2 - n
```

that is equal to

```
n(n-1)/2
```

Comment: came here from the same algorithm problem!