# Number of pairs that can be made with X elements without repeating a pair?

Tags: database, math, combinations, permutation, mathematical-optimization

I would like to make pairs out of X number of database objects.

- Order of pairs does not matter.
- Pairs will be made over multiple rounds.
- I do not want pairs to be repeated in a subsequent round.

If I have:

```
A
B
C
D
```

The first round might be:

```
AB
CD
```

Second round might be:

```
AD
CB
```

Third round might be:

```
AC
DB
```

And there would be no other possibilities.

So for 4 elements, I could do 3 rounds before I have to repeat a pair.

What is the formula to help me with this for any number of elements?

Related [How do I get the total number of unique pairs of a set in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859430/how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-unique-pairs-of-a-set-in-the-database)

Comment: You only want to create two unique pairs per round? 
Edit: Sorry, after thinking about it it was a stupid question

Comment: you only want, non repeating, unique pairs, so `AB` and `BA` would count as the same?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) algorithm to generate all possible pairs. Your example shows r-r algo in action: make two rows of elements, fix the first one (A) and rotate other elements in cyclic manner.

Note that N elements form `N*(N-1)/2` pairs, and `(N-1)` rounds are needed to generate all of them